# Чета, влюблённая друг в друга, - можно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> Ни один из очевидцев не может не упомянуть, рассуждая о Карле Бурбоне
>   и его маленькой Марии Амалии Саксонской, что эта была удивительная
>   пара. Настолько некрасивая – насколько бесконечно влюблённая друг в
>   друга…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получается ещё и "бесконечно некрасивая" - что-то надо сократить. "Влюблённая чета" бывает (часто в книжках встречается), но без сравнительных степеней и "друг друга".

> Примечательно некрасивой была эта пара бесконечно влюблённых друг в друга.

Answer (score 2):

1. ...что этО была удивительная пара.
2. ...что эта пара была удивительна: настолько некрасива — насколько бесконечна и красива была их любовь друг к другу...

Comment: Ага, спасибо. Пропустила глазнушку. Вариант правки шлю автору!

Answer (score 1):

1. Тяжелое нагромождение *ни* и *не*, к тому же корявое: каждый очеведец упоминал? Где упоминал, при каких обстоятельствах? Если каждый очевидец, то не мог не **рассказать** об этом. Или не мог не упомнянуть **в своих рассказах**. Или каждый **рассказчик** не мог не упомянуть.
2. Мой вариант: **...что эта была удивительная пара настолько же сильно влюбленная, насколько  и некрасивая.** Или так: **...что эта была удивительная пара поразительно некрасивых и бесконечно влюблённых друг в друга людей.**

Answer (score 0):

Чета влюблённых друг в друга. (Друг и друг — есть множество.)